# AngularJS On selecting radio button set select field value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How do I set the select fields value by clicking radio button

[image: like the one below]

Comment: please give your html and controller code @dragonfly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio"
   ng-model="string"
   value="string"
   [name="string"]
   [ng-change="string"]
   ng-value="string">
```

Value Used :- 
The value to which the ngModel expression should be set when selected. Note that value only supports string values, i.e. the scope model needs to be a string, too. Use ngValue if you need complex models (number, object, ...).